# BMI Calculator Feet to Inches Conversion Wrong

Tags: javascript

[image]

The image above is a screenshot of a BMI calculator I'm working on at the moment.

The JavaScript code below is supposed to convert value supplied in the feet label (ftheight) box into inches and then add it up to value supplied into the Inches label (inheight) then multiply the result by 2.54 to convert it to centimeters(cm).

The BMI result given is wrong if for example, Weight is 75kg, Height is 5ft 9", BMI result shows 0.31 instead of 24.42. But when I changed the value for feet to 0 or blank and value for inches to 69, it gave the correct result of 24.42

HTML

```
<form name="bmiForm">
        Your Weight(kg): <br><br>
        <input type="text" name="weight" size="10"><br />

        Your Height: <br><br>
        Feet: &nbsp; <input type="number" name="ftheight" size="10"> 
        &nbsp; Inches: &nbsp; <input type="number" name="inheight" size="10"><br />

        <input type="button" value="Calculate BMI" onClick="calculateBmi()"><br /><br />

        Your BMI: <br><input class="bmiresult" name="bmi" size="10"><br />

        This Means: <br><input class="bmimean" name="meaning" size="25"><br />
        <input type="reset" value="Reset" /> </form>
```

JAVASCRIPT

```
function calculateBmi() {
var weight = document.bmiForm.weight.value
var result = 2.54 * (document.bmiForm.ftheight.value * 12 + document.bmiForm.inheight.value)
var height = result
if(weight > 0 && height > 0){   
var finalBmi = weight/(height/100*height/100)
document.bmiForm.bmi.value = finalBmi
if(finalBmi < 18.5){
document.bmiForm.meaning.value = "Hmm... you are too thin."
}
if(finalBmi > 18.5 && finalBmi < 25){
document.bmiForm.meaning.value = "Yah! you are healthy."
}
if(finalBmi > 25){
document.bmiForm.meaning.value = "Oops... you are overweight."
}
}
else{
alert("Please Fill in everything correctly")
}
}
```

What I want is to first convert value supplied into the feet box into inches and add it up to the value supplied in the Inches box and multiply the result by 2.54 to give me value for `var height`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I changed the weight input to type number (to keep it consistent with other inputs), and then called [parseFloat](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/parseFloat) on the input values (as input values are usually stored as text by default, not numbers).

You could change this to be [parseInt](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/parseInt) for ft and inch values if you want to restrict the values to integers though.

If you find that the output is "ugly", you can constrain the number of decimals you show in the result by using [toFixed](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number/toFixed) as well.

```js
function calculateBmi() {
  var weight = parseFloat(document.bmiForm.weight.value);
  var ftHeight = parseFloat(document.bmiForm.ftheight.value);
  var inHeight = parseFloat(document.bmiForm.inheight.value);
  var height = 2.54 * (ftHeight * 12 + inHeight);
  
  if(weight > 0 && height > 0){   
    var finalBmi = weight / (height / 100 * height / 100)
    document.bmiForm.bmi.value = finalBmi
    if(finalBmi < 18.5){
      document.bmiForm.meaning.value = "Hmm... you are too thin."
    } else if(finalBmi > 18.5 && finalBmi < 25){
      document.bmiForm.meaning.value = "Yah! you are healthy."
    } else if(finalBmi > 25){
      document.bmiForm.meaning.value = "Oops... you are overweight."
    }
  } else{
      alert("Please Fill in everything correctly")
  }
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
  <title>JS Bin</title>
</head>
<body>
  <form name="bmiForm">
    Your Weight(kg): <br><br>
    <input type="number" name="weight" size="10"><br />

    Your Height: <br><br>
    Feet: &nbsp; <input type="number" name="ftheight" size="10"> 
    &nbsp; Inches: &nbsp; <input type="number" name="inheight" size="10"><br />

    <input type="button" value="Calculate BMI" onClick="calculateBmi()"><br /><br />

    Your BMI: <br><input class="bmiresult" name="bmi" size="10"><br />

    This Means: <br><input class="bmimean" name="meaning" size="25"><br />
    <input type="reset" value="Reset" />
  
  </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure what you're doing wrong, but this worked for me https://jsfiddle.net/vxshwk2w/

Try using `id` instead of `name`.